# How do I block unknown bots to my sites?

Tags: html, .htaccess, robots.txt

We are getting bruteforce attacked on our sites and I am afraid to ban the IP's as they may be rotating IP's or legitimate users at some point in there life span.

I would like to block all unknown bots from accessing my site. Specifically my /wp-login.php file.

I have spent hours trying to find the code to do this. I am open to suggestions of course. But is there anyway to ban the unknown bots but not ban google and such?

I have captcha setup on my login form and limiting login attempts to 3 fails then lockout for 36 hours then 2 more fails and lockout for 96 hours. This however is not slowing down the attacks and they seem to have an endless pool of IP's to choose from.

**What I ended up doing on top of generally tightening WP security is locking access to wp-login.php and wp-admin folder.
Very easy and quick setup guide here http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/wordpress-login-brute-force-attack for the wp-login.php file
Locking a folder can be done easily in any Cpanel or plesk.**

Comment: I see based on your tags that you are thinking about .htaccess and/or robots.txt, which are both useless at blocking malicious bots because these kinds of bots simply ignore the robots file and most likely pretend to be a regular browser (UA spoofing).

Comment: I think the first goal would be to figure out how they differential from normal traffic..  If you can't, you might just have to throttle a single IP to a certain number of requests per second.

Comment: Since this seems to be a Wordpress Site, there are a lot of great security plugins that can help.  I've had good success with Better Wordpress Security (now called iThemes).  Lots of tools to limit traffic from certain IPs, etc.  Info at http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can block access to the wp-admin directory using an htpasswd file. Generate and htpasswd file using [this tool](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/). Then create a new htaccess file in the wp-admin directory with these contents:

```
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "Admins Only"
    AuthUserFile /directory/with/htpasswd/file/
    AuthType basic
    require user putyourusernamehere
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
```

Comment: The thing is that wp-login is already protected by PHP password, so adding yet another one look like overkill

Comment: I was unsure if this will help. They are trying to login but are unsuccessful. The /wp-login.php file is in the root of the site not in the wp-admin directory.

Comment: @RobMcg : updated the code to match wp-login.php
Not overkill, bots cannot autofill the browser prompt they get with the htpasswd file as they can the normal HTML form.

Comment: I am very willing to give this a try and the logic sounds solid. Can you help me implement it fully? I am not very good with server stuff. I know what the .htaccess file is an where but is there anything additional I need to add to the code of it besides the above?

Comment: @RobMcg it's all about automating Basic HTTP auth, right? To automate it a bot would just need to add a single 'Authorization' header. Something like: Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==. Why do you think that it can't be automated? It's actually more vulnerable than the original PHP based login where you can at least implement a user lockout.

Comment: <FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "Admins Only"
    AuthUserFile /home/jray/public_html/
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthType basic
    require user blog2
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
 adding this to the top of the htaccess file gives me a 500 error currently. I did create a .htpasswd file in the same place as the

Comment: @OlegGryb I feel like this would at least offload the extra handling of the database load times for the normal users. I dont see how it would hurt?

Comment: Remove the `AuthGroupFile` line from my code, I will edit it.

Comment: @OlegGryb So, lets pretend the bot gets through the htpasswd protection (doubt that some generic bot could do this) now all they get to is the wordpress login screen where you can implement a lockout. How is this more overkill than you suggestion of editing the htaccess code every time you need to login?

Comment: This is still rendering a 500 error but I found this.http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/wordpress-login-brute-force-attack I will report back soon. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It's an overkill because your admin users will have to enter two passwords instead of one.

Comment: @RobMcg... and I was reacting on this statement "bots cannot autofill the browser prompt" when was writing about 'Authorization' header.

Comment: I got it working. Thanks very much man, 1 step closer to feeling more secure :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can block a bot from accessing your site, as a bot can *mimic* any legitimate HTTP traffic.

Instead, you should focus on blocking bad *behavior* on your site.

You mention they're trying to brute force attack your site.  What does this mean?  Are they flooding your site with so much traffic, it slows down your servers?  If so, perhaps throttle a single IP to a certain number of requests per second.  If one IP, for example, sends 100 requests a second to your service, block them for 30 seconds.

Is this bot trying to guess passwords?  If so, track bad password attempts and prevent another attempt for five seconds.  Or, use something like CAPTCHAs to slow down automated password change attempts, or suspicious logons.

A lot of these strategies can be implemented with routers, third party libraries and, if you're using WordPress, [WordPress plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have captcha setup on my login form and limiting login attempts to 3 fails then lockout for 36 hours then 2 more fails and lockout for 96 hours. This however is not slowing down the attacks and they seem to have an endless pool of IP's to choose from.

Comment: Yea, in my opinion that's a DoS vulnerability.  A bot can just lock out everyone's account now.  I think login attempts should have like a 5 second delay or something.  It would take someone 1,000yrs to brute force guess a password.  If they flood your server with traffic, I don't think there's much you can do about that.  If you can control more bandwidth than a site has, you can take them down.

Comment: At this point I am thinking of deleting the login page from the server and putting it back when I need it. Although I am not sure if this would just open the entire site free range.

Comment: Yea if it's just that one page and no one else but you needs to access it, give it some weird name.  Then the attackers will just get 404 errors.

Comment: If you need access plus a small group of other trusted admins, give it a weird name and tell others the new name, then make sure it never gets out heh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following trick at my WordPress website:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^<root-path>/wp-login\.php.*$ <root-path>/?error=404 [L]
```

It will return "Page not Found" if somebody tries to access the login page. When I need to access the login page myself, I simply comment out the last line in my .htaccess file.

The .htaccess file is located in my root web folder.

Comment: this would be perfect but several legitimate users need to edit the site randomly

Comment: Agree, it might be problematic if you have many users accessing admin pages, but in the case when admins have access to the web site folders as well, it'll work. Definitely works for me since I'm the only admin at my site :)

Comment: If you are using this type of solution you could add a rule that check for a specific query string value: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)letmein=true($|&)` if that query string is not present just redirect back to index page. This way you dont have to edit the htaccess file every time you want to update the site.

Comment: Good point that can be used for multiple users, but since you start using a certain secret in a query string, it can't be considered as a secret anymore, so it's less secure in my view.

Answer (score 1):

I tested yesterday Hide My Wp from Theme Forest and was very impressed with what it can do. It might just be what you're looking for. Check it out at: http://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-no-one-can-know-you-use-wordpress/4177158